# Pasting file not work from clipboard on react (updated -> about clipboard permission)

Tags: reactjs, clipboard, data-transfer

I want to impement to file upload by paste from clipboard.

so, i tried that get a file object from onPaste.

```
const handlePaste = (e) => {
  console.log(e.clipboardData.items[0])
}
<MessageInput
  ...
  onPaste={handlePaste}
>
```

and, i got a data in console.log

```
DataTransferItem {kind: "string", type: "text/plain"}
kind: ""
type: ""
__proto__: DataTransferItem
```

Although i copied image clearly. Why?

How can i get file from clipboard by pasting?

-- update --

if i set permission about clipboard for this page, i can get file object from clipboard.

then, how can i request permission about clipboard to user?
It is not work.

````
navigator.permissions.query({
      name: 'clipboard-read',
    }).then(permissionStatus => {
      // Will be 'granted', 'denied' or 'prompt':
      console.log(permissionStatus.state):

      // Listen for changes to the permission state
      permissionStatus.onchange = () => {
        console.log(permissionStatus.state)
      }
    })
```
````

Comment: `<MessageInput />` is not a standard ReactJS component. Can you provide the source or a link to the source?
If you are using the native browser `onPaste` event handler, then you need to ensure that you have set the `ContentEditable` attribute to true in the actual DOM node https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Editable_content

Comment: <MessageInput /> is a just functional component. it wrap a textarea component